# MVVM Messaging Framework alone

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, dialog

This question is going to be rather short and quick to answer.

I am doing a project using MVVM design pattern in View-First approach. I'm currently using my own implementation for almost everything but I don't wanna reinvent the wheel when it comes to create a Messaging feature to make my ViewModels able to communicate data. So is there a Messaging Framework just like the one implemented in MVVM Light? Cause I'd like not to import the whole framework only for one class.

Another accepted solution would be if there was a way in MVVM View-First to make a dialog and get its ViewModel's values

Comment: Perhaps you could just add a reference to the MVVM Light messaging DLL? That's assuming there is one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally found what I wanted : Caliburn.Micro offers his EventAggregator (Other name for Messaging) as a separate Framework. It's exactly what I'm looking for I can now make my ViewModels communicate with when using dialogs